# How to save .net Identity data in DB via web api

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, google-authentication

Im quite new with web development and trying to create a website on public server which will store data on a local DB server via web api. I got it working to a degree where I can post or get data from my web app. Now, I need to implement (google and WS-federation) log in mechanism so I decided to use Identity which seems to be doing majority of the things for me which is great, it creates DB with necessary tables to store log in info.

[image: Auto generated identity DB tables]

But I'm struggling to set up identity to store that data in DB via web api. Is that incorrect way of doing authorisation? I'm a bit lost on this one so any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do that is to use tokens for validation. So that you can do Google authentication by another server and then use that token to use Web APIs.

[image: for details implementation you can use IdentityServer4]

[IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/?msclkid=0b48451cc80d11ecaa6991a425942c61)

Comment: Thanks @thisisnabi, after some reading it looks like that's most likely what I will end up using. My main problem is, I want to keep some of the log in data on a local server (email address, username etc), I guess I could use external claims for it and get that data? But then I need to post that data via web api to local DB, is that a good practice of doing?